# Android apps crash on startup

Tags: android, codenameone

Everytime I send an Android app through, whether is is a full app or a hello world app, the application crashes on startup.

When I run logcat, I get the following error:

```
W/System.err( 2426): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/power_supply/battery/lcd: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

W/System.err( 2426):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)

W/System.err( 2426):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)

W/System.err( 2426):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)

W/System.err( 2426):    at com.sec.android.hardware.SecHardwareInterface.setBatteryADC(SecHardwareInterface.java:392)

W/System.err( 2426):    at com.android.server.power.PowerManagerService$DisplayBlankerImpl$1.run(PowerManagerService.java:5279)

W/System.err( 2426):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

W/System.err( 2426):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

W/System.err( 2426):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)

I/PowerManagerService( 2426): [PWL]       PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK              'ActivityManager-Sleep' (uid=1000, pid=2426, ws=null) (elapsedTime=24)

I/PowerManagerService( 2426): [PWL]   PowerManagerService.Broadcasts: ref count=1

W/System.err( 2426):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

W/System.err( 2426): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

W/System.err( 2426):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)

W/System.err( 2426):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)

W/System.err( 2426):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)

W/System.err( 2426):    ... 8 more
```

This happens on Android 4.4.2, on a Samsung GT-N7100.

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: Could you please add some more information? These are apps you are (trying to) develope? Which Development environment are you using?

Comment: Hi,
I am using the codenameone development environmnet. This issue seems to be a recent development possibly originating from their build servers. I chose to use that platform to create an Android app, which resulted in this error even with their Hello World application, thus eliminating many possibilities that could arise with a full-fledged application.

Comment: These logs are pointing to your Android OS, look for logs that points to `com.yourcompanyname.yourappname`. Try testing your app on another android device to see if the problem is the same.

Comment: i think you have to report this issue to codenameone. the app they are building might have other codes you are not aware of, even if your app is just `hello world`, so this additions codes causes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log is partial but it seems that some cases that rely on Google Play Services in various ways failed with an update we deployed today. This should be working now as we reverted that fix.

We'll deploy a more conservative change at a later date.